# What's that Manga where the dude keeps asking out a girl until she says yes but it's revealed he's dead?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I would just like to know the name of the manga because I kinda just lost it to time. The whole time this guy keeps asking out this girl until she says yes but it's revealed he's been dead and he can't move on until she accepts that fact.

Comment: Is that the ending of the manga then? Is it a one-shot or do other things happen in the meantime?

Comment: What other things can you remember? When did you read it, what did the characters look like, where does it take place, &c.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely *[49 Kaime no Kokuhaku](https://anilist.co/manga/132571/49-Kaime-no-Kokuhaku/)* or *49th Confession*. It is a oneshot manga by Hakuto Rin.

> Takanashi Haruki, the typical bad boy character in shoujo manga, confessed to Azuha. Azuha rejected him, only to find him chasing her days after days. However, this chase must soon come to an end or else...?

As a oneshot, there isn't much to it beyond what is described in the confession. The female lead is confessed to by a guy, and it is shown that she holds feelings for a classmate that recently died. The twist is that the man confessing to her in the story is the dead classmate.

[image]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Love Confession/s` and `plot twist`.